# What does ai_addr contain?

Tags: c++, server, ip, ip-address

I am currently learning socket programming and while programming I noticed that in a lot of functions you need to Pass in stuff from `addrinfo*`, and I understand what most of the stuff does. But my Question is: What exactly is ai_addr? It is never specified by me, though if I let the Programm output me the value that it has, I get a wierd Hash-like result. It's a mix of Numbers and Letters, though the first 5 symbols seem to be always 000000. I have assumed that it was the IP or TCP of a local Network, but to me, what I get output does not seem like a IP adress, and since i am using `AF_INET` as a Network family it should be a IPx4 address, but it is not.

When i look in the libary in which ai_addr is defined i also can't find a answer and looking online also hasn't helped me.
My Current Code:

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

WSADATA wsaData;

int main()
{
    int iResult;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

    struct addrinfo* result = NULL, * ptr = NULL, hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << result->ai_addr << ' ' << result->ai_addrlen;

    if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ClientSocket;

    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
```

Also I use Visual Studio 2021 Community edition.

Comment: Maybe not an answer, but I would advise you to spent time learning something like boost asio for socket programming (or another C++ socket library). It is a much better fit for C++ (and bonus, code can usually also be compiled for linux). For example : [synchronous tcp socket server](https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/Boost/boost_AsynchIO_asio_tcpip_socket_server_client_timer_bind_handler_multithreading_synchronizing_network_D.php) (though I wouldn't use the "using namespace" code shown there)

Comment: The `ai_addr` member is a pointer to a socket address structure. Technically it's a `struct sockaddr *`, which can be converted (cast) to the correct socket address structure. Which is well-documented and should be quite obvious in any example.

Comment: *"It's a mix of Numbers and Letters, though the first 5 symbols seem to be always 000000."* **Seems like a pointer.**

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's a punned type, whose tag is the size parameter of called function. It may well be a pointer to a `sockaddr_in` or other address types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket API supports many different ways of specifying the address of each endpoint in the communication, depending on the socket's type.

The 1st parameter of the `socket()` call specifies the type of address family to be used for all subsequent API calls on the socket that deal with endpoints.

Each address family defines its own unique `sockaddr_...` struct type to carry its particular address information.

All socket API functions that accept/return a socket address will take a generic `sockaddr*` pointer as a parameter, which must be typecasted in order to access the struct data. The 1st field of all `sockaddr_...` types must specify its family so the API/receiver knows how to access the `struct` data correctly.

The `ai_addr` field is a `sockaddr*` pointer to a `sockaddr_...` struct that is appropriate to the family specified in the `ai_family` field.

For example:

- when the `ai_family` is `AF_INET` (IPv4) then `ai_addr` points to a `sockaddr_in` struct containing the IPv4 address and port.
- when the `ai_family` is `AF_INET6` (IPv6) then `ai_addr` points to a `sockaddr_in6` struct containing the IPv6 address, port, and scope id.
- when the `ai_family` is `AF_UNIX` (UNIX domain) then `ai_addr` points to a `sockaddr_un` struct containing a filesystem path.
- when the `ai_family` is `AF_BTH` (Bluetooth) then `ai_addr` points to a `sockaddr_bth` struct containing the ID and port of a paired Bluetooth device.
- etc...